# Does cnosdb have a solution for log collection, storage and viewing?

Tags: cnosdb

Prometheus, which is also a time series database, has a complete monitoring system. There is also the famous elk scheme in the java structure. So does cnosdb have something similar? When I use cnosdb, I can quickly build a monitoring or at least a log management system to avoid introducing other similar products into my project?